# Prevent entire field in Access form from being highlighted

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

When I scroll to the next record in an Access form, whatever field I am in gets highlighted once scrolled to the next record. How do I prevent the highlight of the entire field?

Users are having issues where they are accidentally deleting with one click because the entire field is highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the behaviour set under Options, Behaviour Entering Field.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172326(v=office.11).aspx